# Magento2: Custom validation in checkout address form

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, form-validation, ui-form, custom-validation

I'm trying to add a custom validation to some input fields in checkout address forms.
The [official guide](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/validations/custom-rules/) works fine on addressbook and other forms, extending `mage/validator` and using *addMethod* is simply and clean.

But for checkout address fields another library is used (why?!): `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator` which *addRule* lacks of many useful things. I would like to implement a rule that uses some jQuery function on the element (ie: checking the `$(element).prop('disabled')` status), but I can't figure how to get the field element because every rule calls has only value and params as parameters.

I read all the code in:

```
    ./vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/validator.js
    ./vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
    ./vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/utils.js
```

and many docs (ie: [official doc](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/) and many StackExchange threads), searching for a way to get the element where the rule is applied, but I can't find anything useful. The only way I found is passing `input[name="the_input_name"]` as parameter, but it won't work if there more than one input with *the_input_name* (ie: the same field name appears in shipping and payment addresses). Also seems impossible to clean up validation errors via jQuery.

After many hour of searching, trying and debugging I gave up and here I am, asking for help.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found a solution: instead using validator, I'm creating a new component extending `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` and writing my logic in `validate` method, so I can test the checked status of an input and conditionally validate another input.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Magento by default validation or custom Js Validation in the checkout Address Form

List of the Magento default validation rules :

```
validate-grouped-qty

validate-one-checkbox-required-by-name

validate-date-between

validate-dob

max-words

min-words

range-words

letters-with-basic-punc

alphanumeric

letters-only

no-whitespace

zip-range

integer

vinUS

dateITA

dateNL

time

time12h

phoneUS

phoneUK

mobileUK

stripped-min-length

email2

url2

credit-card-types

ipv4

ipv6

pattern

allow-container-className
```

You can also use this link for more details "

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/validations/rule-list/

If you need more help, you can ping me again