# Magento 2.4: Billing address city field validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

I want to make the billing address **city** field **required** on the checkout.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the Magento default rules validation for this in the form of your checkout.

You can check the fields of the form, If there is UI component then use can just add these lines in the form.

```
<validation>
    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
               </validation>
```

Or you can add the any JS vaidation.

Comment: I think this may help you. https://magecomp.com/blog/make-state-required-for-checkout-in-magento-2/

Comment: I am asking about the 'City' field.

Comment: You can also make the required as similar like other fields

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: These are the list of the some Magento validations : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360357/magento2-custom-validation-in-checkout-address-form/360470#360470

Comment: Let me know If you want more help

Comment: Thanks. I want to know how can I make the field required programmatically?

Comment: I followed this but it is not working. 
https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-validation-to-address-field-in-checkout-in-magento-2/

Comment: First, you can check the fields where its the comming.

Comment: You can check my updated answer

Comment: @RanaZain on checkout in shipping and billing address field city is required by default. Do you have any changes for you checkout?

Comment: What type of changes you want for the checkout